# Why isn't forked repository showing contributions?

Tags: github, repository

I pushed a few commits to my forked repository.
I can see my commits in the commit history in my forked repository, but my contributions isn't showing the commit activity..
Is it because I pushed to forked repository, not my repository..?
Is there any way to show contributions of forked repository?

https://github.com/devjoylee/estimate-board

Comment: If you mean the Contributors block in the sidebar: because it's a fork. The committers to the upstream may not even know your fork exists, so it would be misleading to present them as contributors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GitHub states that commits made in a fork won't be counted as a contribution in the contribution graph in your profile. Pull requests and issues are counted IIRC.

Here's where I found the reference: https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-graphs-on-your-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile

I hope this helped. Thank you!

Comment: Why would that be the rule? Why not give the same incentive to contribute to your repos as forked repos? I would think it would be best to foster open source work just as much as personal work.

Comment: @steezeburger i agree with that :(